# How can the filecontents environment be used with a build directory?

Tags: auxiliary-files, filecontents

Having updated an old template for a paper I wanted also to clean up the way the document gets built by having a dedicated build directory.

Using TexStudio it works (mostly) by changing:

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
bibtex.exe %
biber.exe %
```

to

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --aux-directory=build %.tex
bibtex.exe --include-directory=build %
biber.exe --input-directory=build --output-directory=build %
```

My template  makes use of the `filecontents` environment (the standalone one is deprecated so I switched) to ease sorting abbreviations (sorting is done externally since I haven't found a LaTeX internal solution):

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{abbreviations.tex}
  \acro{TLA}{Three Letter Acronym}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{acronym}
    \IfFileExists{abbreviations-sorted}{\input{abbreviations-sorted}}{\input{abbreviations}}
\end{acronym}
```

The file `abbreviations.tex` gets created in the `build` directory which is not necessarily expected since without a name it would be more plausible to have it along the document. I fixed the loading of the created file via `\input` by adding the `build/` prefix.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{abbreviations.tex}
  \acro{TLA}{Three Letter Acronym}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{acronym}
    \IfFileExists{build/abbreviations-sorted}{\input{build/abbreviations-sorted}}{\input{build/abbreviations}}
\end{acronym}
```

It looks a bit unclean / hacky since it doesn't match the filename used by `filecontents` and depends on the build environment. Is there way to make it "clean" again?

Comment: well the clean way is imho not to use a build directory. it is a quite foreign idea to tex as -- as you realized -- the files it creates are not only output, but often also input. But beside this, I would have expected that abbreviation.tex is found as the build folder is in the search path.

Comment: Having some software background that's the way I usually do my coding projects.  As I use git for versioning it makes it also very easy to ingore changed content of the `build` directory.
I wonder what you mean by search path. Is this something I can change myself? I'm using MikTex on Windows and found there an option under `Settings` => `Directories`. Is this it?

Comment: well tex finds the aux-file and the toc-file in the build folder, so I would expect it to find also abbreviations.tex,  imho simply \input{abbreviations} should work, it is really created there. And a tex document is not like a standard coding project. They normally have distinct input and output files. But in tex files are often both.

Comment: Thanks a lot @UlrikeFischer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation I found the error to be resulting from the usage of

`--aux-directory=build`.

After changing it to

`--output-directory=build`

the build went as expected without requiring to add the `build/` prefix within the document.

Now TexStudio failed to find the created document PDF for preview (since it was also created within the `build` directory). This was solved by changing

`Options -> Configure -> Build -> Build Options -> Additional Search Paths`

to:

- Log File: `./build`
- PDF File: `./build`